# Corner case in Huffman Algorithm

Tags: compression, huffman-code

I am trying to solve by hand two different scenarios of compression via Huffman algorithm, In each one of them, we start with an ordered queue that contains tuples `(symbol, frequency)` as its items, and we'll try to form a dictionary:

```
step 0:
[c:3] [b:4] [a:5]

step 1:
[a:5]    [7]
     [c:3] [b:4]

step 2:
     [12]
[a:5]    [7]
     [c:3] [b:4]
```

if we consider the left to be 0 and the right to be 1, then we have as dictionary:

```
a -> 0
b -> 11
c -> 10
```

Until now, everything looks right. But let's assume our initial queue was something like the following, instead:

```
step 0:
[c:1] [b:2] [a:4]

step 1:
    [3]      [a:4]
[c:1] [b:2]

step 2:
         [7]
    [3]      [a:4]
[c:1] [b:2]
```

that yields the following dictionary:

```
a -> 1
b -> 01
c -> 00
```

which doesn't seem right (both `a` and `b` are equal).

What am I doing wrong? I could just do an `if` to see in the root of the tree which one of the branches is actually a leaf, selecting that direction to be the 1's direction, but this doesn't seem clean to me. I guess I must be missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the **sequence** of bits in the dictionary should not cause ambiguity when decoding. The value of the sequence doesn't matter.

Ambiguity is resolved in Huffman coding by the condition that only the leaf in the coding tree can hold the character to be encoded. The tree above follows this rule, so there is no problem with the resulting encoding.

Comment: There is in the 2nd case a problem, as when encoding this as bits, both "a" and "b" will be encoded as 1.

Comment: @devouredelysium: Like I said, it is the sequence, and not the value. When you do encoding, you will replace the character with the whole sequence. So "ab" --> 101, "ba" --> 011, "bb" --> 0101, "aa" --> 11

Comment: @devouredelysium aaa and bbb are encoded differently: 111 and 010101. If you store the length of the sequence also, they're not the same.

Answer (score 2):

The bit sequences are not equal. If you have a bit string like:

01100

Then it can only be decompressed as "bac". You have to store the compression result in a way that preserves leading zeroes in the sequence, so for example the above could be padded to 01100000 or 00001100 to fill a byte of output and then stored along with the length 5. Of course the issue is only with the first or last byte of output, depending on which side you choose to pad.

Comment: When writing to the actual file, I'll want to do it with the byte values, and not with the shown strings. For instance, in Java, both "a"(=1) and "b"(=01) would degenerate into a (byte)1, which means that this dictionary is ambiguous. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You don't store the byte values of huffman bit sequences, because then you would acieve very bad compression. Instead you have to pack several sequences into the same byte as far as possible. Often sequences are also split between bytes.

Comment: For example to compress abcabcabc you store 10100101 00101000 and the length 15. I had to add a 0 in the end to make it fill the 2 bytes. So the file contents might be the bytes 0, 15, 165, 40 or in hex 000fa528, thus containing the length encoded in 2 bytes and the data in the following bytes. This would give you a maximum encoded file size of 8194 bytes.

Comment: @devouredelysium: Just to add to jjrv's comment, when you encode/compress data with Huffman coding, you will produce a stream of bits, not bytes.